# React - map n times group of input fields and take their value into array of objects

Tags: reactjs, input, array.prototype.map, input-field

I am trying to map one react element for n times.
Element consist two input fields: x and y.

I have managed to do this, but when I enter some value in x field, all x fields on all Element are getting that value.

Second part of problem is when I try to take values of input fields into array of objects (eg. [{x:10, y:20},{x:30, y:70},{x:100, y:5}]), there is error that "Map is not a function."

Here is code and CodePen link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-shape-d250yz?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import SecondForm from "./SecondForm";

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const [fieldsCount, setFieldsCount] = useState(0);

  const [xPolygonInput, setXInput] = useState(0);
  const [yPolygonInput, setYInput] = useState(0);

  let secondForm = document.getElementsByClassName("second-form");
  console.log(secondForm);

  let items = [];

  let createArrayOfObjects = () => {
    console.log(xPolygonInput, yPolygonInput);
    items.push(
      secondForm.map(() => {
        return {
          x: { xPolygonInput },
          y: { yPolygonInput }
        };
      })
    );
    console.log(items);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Check is point inide of polygon or not</h1>
      <div className="start-form">
        <p>Select number from 3 to 10 for number of Polygon angles</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="nr-of-angles"
          name="nr-ofangles"
          min="3"
          max="10"
          required
          ref={inputRef}
        ></input>
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => setFieldsCount(inputRef.current.value)}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="coordinates">
        <div className="coordinates-wrap">
          <div className="angle-wrapper">
            <p>Angle Coordinates</p>
            <div className="angle-inner">
              {Array(parseInt(fieldsCount))
                .fill()
                .map((i, index) => (
                  <SecondForm
                    id={index}
                    key={index}
                    xPolygonInput={xPolygonInput}
                    yPolygonInput={yPolygonInput}
                    setXInput={setXInput}
                    setYInput={setYInput}
                    className="second-form"
                  >
                    <p>Group {index + 1}</p>
                  </SecondForm>
                ))}
            </div>
            <br />
            <button onClick={createArrayOfObjects} className="btn">
              Create Array of Objects
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Replacing react element with simple html code did not helped.
First part of problem (repeating input on all x or y fields) may have some connection with .fill(), but if I remove it map does not work...
Any help is welcomed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing the entire positions (x, y) as an array of objects.

Callback would then update the correct position based on index (or ID if applicable).

You can take a look at the example code below.

`SecondForm.jsx`

```
function SecondForm({ x, y, onXChange, onYChange }) {
  // const [input, setInput] = useState(props?.value ?? '');

  return (
    <div className="angle-input">
      <form>
        {/* <label>Enter X and Y coordinates for Polygon angles</label> */}
        <div className="angle-coordinates">
          <p>Angle</p>
          <input
            type="number"
            min="0"
            max="500"
            placeholder="x"
            className="xPolygon"
            name="nr-ofangles"
            value={x}
            onChange={onXChange}
            required
          ></input>
          <input
            type="number"
            min="0"
            max="400"
            placeholder="y"
            className="yPolygon"
            name="nr-ofangles"
            value={y}
            onChange={onYChange}
            required
          ></input>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SecondForm;
```

`App.jsx`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import SecondForm from "./SecondForm";

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);

  const handleCreatePositions = () => {
    const pos = Array.from(
      { length: parseInt(inputRef.current.value, 10) },
      () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 })
    );
    setPositions(pos);
  };

  const handleOnInputChange = (e, index, axis) => {
    setPositions((prevPositions) => {
      const newPositions = [...prevPositions];
      newPositions[index] = {
        ...newPositions[index],
        [axis]: e.target.value
      };
      return newPositions;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Check is point inide of polygon or not</h1>
      <div className="start-form">
        <p>Select number from 3 to 10 for number of Polygon angles</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="nr-of-angles"
          name="nr-ofangles"
          min="3"
          max="10"
          required
          ref={inputRef}
        ></input>
        <button className="btn" onClick={handleCreatePositions}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="coordinates">
        <div className="coordinates-wrap">
          <div className="angle-wrapper">
            <p>Angle Coordinates</p>
            <div className="angle-inner">
              {positions.map((position, index) => (
                <SecondForm
                  id={index}
                  key={index}
                  x={position.x}
                  y={position.y}
                  onXChange={(e) => handleOnInputChange(e, index, "x")}
                  onYChange={(e) => handleOnInputChange(e, index, "y")}
                  className="second-form"
                >
                  <p>Group {index + 1}</p>
                </SecondForm>
              ))}
            </div>
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => console.log(positions)} className="btn">
              Create Array of Objects
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit 74428251]

Comment: Thanks for help @junwen-k problem is solved! :D